# New oData Feed in PWA

Tags: custom-list, odata, pwa

Is there a way to create a new oData feed in PWA?

I would like to build a new custom list that has similar properties to the issues/risk lists in that it would have its own oData feed.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you want to export data to excel please [here](https://projectserverblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/22/project-server-excel-sync-using-odata/) to view related blog post.

If you want to customize OData feed, consider using Power Query. It allows you to merge the tables and choose the columns you want.

- Download Power Query for excel. (It is free for Microsoft site)
- Map OData feed using Power Query. (similar to basic process)
- Instead of Load click Edit.
- Do your modifications and then Load data.

Every time you refresh data will be fetched in required format.

Hope this helps. Please feel free to revert if you need more clarity.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I am looking to create a new custome oData field though. My end goal is to use it in Power BI.